# Why is this exception thrown when trying to match this regex in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to match a specific string out of a an HTML document and have this regex pattern to grab it:

```
Pattern somePattern = Pattern.compile("var json = ({\"r\":\"^d1\".*});");
```

However when I try to hit that code at runtime, I get this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
 java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX near index 13:
 var json = ({"r":"^d1".*});
              ^
     at com.ibm.icu4jni.regex.NativeRegEx.open(Native Method)
     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Pattern.java:383)
     at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:341)
     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:317)
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to escape the "{}" brace characters as these mean something special to regex.

This is the long hand way of expressing a "count" so`.{0,}`is equivalent to`.* .{0,1}`is equivalent to`.?`and`.{2,4}`means at least two but no more than four of the previous match

Comment: Yep, they're quantifiers: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html